# Why events does not support binding inherited types?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, event-handling

In these delegates:

`EventHandler`

> public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

`FormClosingEventHandler`

> public delegate void FormClosingEventHandler(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e);

`FormClosingEventArgs` is inherited from `EventArgs`. Why can't I bind an `FormClosing` event with an event handler from `EventHandler` delegate?

I know that the event handler's signiture must match its delegate, but why it doesn't suppot matching inherited types ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's interesting...

You *can* bind an eventhandler using a method group conversion with compatible types:

```
public void GenericHandlerMethod(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

...
// Valid
foo.FormClosingEvent += GenericHandlerMethod;
```

This will actually create an instance of `FormClosingEventHandler`, *not* `EventHandler`.

However you can't subscribe *directly* with an existing delegate of type EventHandler:

```
EventHandler genericHandler = GenericHandlerMethod;
// Invalid
foo.FormClosingEvent += genericHandler;
```

... but you *can* create a new delegate based on an existing one, if the types are compatible:

```
EventHandler generic = GenericHandlerMethod;
FormClosingEventHandler closingHandler = new FormClosingEventHandler(generic);
// Valid
foo.FormClosingEvent += closingHandler;
```

Basically you need to remember that all the syntactic sugar is *effectively* calling a method like this:

```
foo.AddFormClosingHandler(handler);
```

where the method has a signature of:

```
public void AddFormClosingHandler(FormClosingHandler handler)
```

Now remember that although they have compatible signatures, there's no reference conversion available from `EventHandler` to `FormClosingHandler`. It's not like one inherits from the other.

It gets even more confusing with generic covariance/contravariance, but we'll leave it there for now... hopefully that's given you something to chew on and options for working round the restrictions.

Comment: Really great answer, Thanks. The only problem is that the IDE which generates the event handlers in UI doesn't support a work arround such this. so I have to bind them manually. For that I asked *logically* why it doesn't supported.

Comment: @John: Bah, I hate Visual Studio when it comes to event handlers. Hopefully the answer explains why the restrictions are present when it comes to actual code - VS restrictions are beyond my understanding ;)

Answer (score 1):

A delegate which points directly to an object method holds three pieces of information:

1. The target object upon which the method should act, or `null` in the case of static methods

   A reference to a function which acts upon that type of object, or a static function if the target is `null`.

   The type of the delegate itself.

A delegate which is produced by using `Delegate.Combine` to combine a total of *N* single-cast delegates will contain *N* targets, *N* methods, and *ONE* delegate type.  Given the (IMHO rather icky and unfortunate) way in which `Delegate.Combine` and `Delegate.Remove` are used, there's no way the system could allow existing uses of `Combine` to accept delegates of different types.

For example, a routine might need an `EventHandler<IFoo>`.  If classes `Moe` and `Larry` both implement `IFoo` and `IBar`, such a routine should be able to accept an `EventHandler<Moe>` or an `EventHandler<Larry>`.  If each delegate type had its own definition for `Combine`, it might be possible to feed `EventHandler<IFoo>.Combine()` a delegate of type `EventHandler<Moe>` and one of `EventHandler<Larry>`, and have it generate a combined delegate handler of type `EventHandler<IFoo>`.  Unfortunately, there's one `Delegate.Combine()` method for all delegate types, and there's no way that it can look at an `EventHandler<Moe>` and an `EventHandler<Larry>` and figure out what type the combined delegate should be (even if `Delegate.Combine` had the ability to identify types to which both event handlers could be cast, it would have no way of knowing whether to use `EventHandler<IFoo>` or `EventHandler<IBar>`).